# How to SELECT same two columns name from two different tables which are using inner join in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In two tables have same column names

```
 Table_1 has full_name,  person_key
             Louis Caron  1                                          
 Table_2 has full_name, subject_key 
             Anne Hebert  1 
SQL Query:
SELECT full_name,full_name FROM Table_2
INNER JOIN Table_1 ON Table_2.subject_key = Table_1.person_key;

OUTPUT
full_name   full_name
Louis Caron Anne Hebert
```

I except the output as above but I got the same name for two columns. Please anyone help me

Comment: Just as @EstevaoLuis answered, you have to add `table prefix` in the `select` clause. In you case, use `SELECT Table_1.full_name, Table_2.full_name` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using alias

```
SELECT t1.full_name, t2.full_name
FROM Table_2 t2
INNER JOIN Table_1 t1
ON t2.subject_key = t1.person_key;
```

Comment: Thanks, Let me do it

Answer (score 0):

SELECT t1.full_name as t1_full_name, t2.full_name as t2_full_name
FROM Table_2 t2
INNER JOIN Table_1 t1
ON t2.subject_key = t1.person_key;

Answer (score 0):

Using a similar code compared to what you use after `JOIN` at the query piece after `ON` code; writing the full table name before the column:

```
SELECT Table_1.full_name, Table_2.full_name
FROM Table_2
INNER JOIN Table_1 ON Table_2.subject_key = Table_1.person_key;
```

Or, as mentioned before, using alias, which i think is the best approach, very similar:

```
SELECT t1.full_name, t2.full_name
FROM Table_2 AS t2
INNER JOIN Table_1 AS t1 ON t2.subject_key = t1.person_key;
```

Based on your SGDB, the syntax to declare an alias can vary from `TableName tn` to `TableName AS tn`. Some SGDB's like postgres may accept both syntaxes.

Also, I would suggest to use an alias to the column names, changing the column names to a better one and making it better to read the values:

```
SELECT
     t1.full_name AS name_A,
     t2.full_name AS name_B
FROM Table_2 AS t2
INNER JOIN Table_1 AS t1 ON t2.subject_key = t1.person_key;
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct @Vinícius Almeida Dos Santos. I got the output what I wanted. Thanks a lot